# показать скрыть элемент по id reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import classes from './DataProvider.css'
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser'

class DataProvider extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      history: [],
      isShowHistory: false,
      activeHistory: null,
    }
    // this.showHistory = this.showHistory.bind(this)
  }

 componentDidMount(){

    axios.get('https://blabla.ru/restapi/api/lead/', {method: 'HEAD', mode: 'no-cors'})
    .then(response => {
      let history = response.data
      this.setState({
        history
      })
      console.log(history);
    })

  }

  showHistory = (id) => {
    this.setState({
      isShowHistory: !this.state.isShowHistory
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        {this.state.history.map((item) => {
          const showHandleHis = () => this.showHistory(item.id);

          return (
            <div className={classes.DataProvider + " col-sm-6 my-2"} key={item.id}>
            <img src={item.image_lead} />
            <h3>{item.name}</h3>
            {ReactHtmlParser(this.state.isShowHistory ? item.history : null)}
            <button className={classes.Button}
              onClick={showHandleHis}>
              {!this.state.isShowHistory ? 'Показать историю' : 'Скрыть историю'}
            </button>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default DataProvider
```

**Не ребит**
мб что то добавить в showHistory? что не пойму и как...

Comment: Может вместо `this.setState({ history })` сделать `this.setState({ history: history })` ?

Comment: я юзаю es6, это одно и тоже), мб кто не понял, у меня рендерится 2ва элемента, и если нажать на кнопку у одного то у второго тоже сработает онклик, мне надо что бы срабатывал на 1элементе, и вот как его привязать на онклик я не пойму... но намекнули про "флаг"...

Comment: как он у вас в бесконечный цикл не падает? в рендере меняете стейт, который вызывает рендер. в showHistory стоит !bla-bla, который переключается при каждом рендере. а поскольку установка стейта процесс асинхронный, то результат должен быть мало предсказуем

Comment: render() — требуется обязательно и возвращает элементы в качестве вывода компонента.
Метод должен быть чистым, т.е. не изменять состояние компонента. Он получает
входные данные в виде свойств и состояния и возвращает элемент.

Comment: крч переписал и вроде работает, отделил провайдера и список историй на разные компоненты и теперь открывается всё как надо, но пока не пойму почему...

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import HistoryList from './HistoryList'


class DataProvider extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      history: [],
    }
  }

 componentDidMount(){

    axios.get('https://blabla.ru/restapi/api/lead/', {method: 'HEAD', mode: 'no-cors'})
    .then(response => {
      let history = response.data
      this.setState({
        history
      })
      console.log(history);
    })

  }


  render(){
    const historyList = this.state.history.map(item => {
      return (
        <div key={item.id}>
            <HistoryList data={item} />
        </div>
      )
    })
    return(
      <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        {historyList}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default DataProvider
```

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import classes from './DataProvider.css'
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser'

class HistoryList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isShowHistory: false,
    }
  }

  showHistory = () => {
    this.setState({
      isShowHistory: !this.state.isShowHistory
    })
  }


  render(){
    const id = this.props.data.id,
          name =  this.props.data.name,
          history =  this.props.data.history,
          image_lead =  this.props.data.image_lead
    return(
      <div className={classes.DataProvider + " col-sm-6 my-2"}>
      <img src={image_lead} />
      <h3>{name}</h3>
      {ReactHtmlParser(this.state.isShowHistory && history)}
      <button className={classes.Button} onClick={this.showHistory}>
        {!this.state.isShowHistory ? 'Показать историю' : 'Скрыть историю'}
      </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default HistoryList
```